# Why isn't any color showing up in my .3mf file in Windows 10 3D Builder

Tags: color

So, I made a 3D picture of a cute mouse using [Microsoft Paint 3D](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/paint-3d/9nblggh5fv99) and exported it as a .3mf.

Why didn't the colors match when I opened the file in [Microsoft 3D Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/3d-builder/9wzdncrfj3t6)?

Comment: How did you make a "3D picture"?

Comment: I used Paint 3D. Forgot to mention it ;p

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of how the mouse looks in each application or point us to a place where we could find the "cute mouse"?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [3MF Specification](http://3mf.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/3MFcoreSpec_1.1.pdf), colors in the .3mf files are [sRGB](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB).

If you are looking at gross color defects, I would look a the raw codes generated in the 3mf to make sure they make sense.

If you are talking about subtle color differences, that is much more complicated.

Color have always been a tough thing to define as it is affected by whether the it is emissive (like displayed on a screen) or reflective (like a physical object).  The way it is perceived is affected by ambient light, surface texture and more.  I worked on a project once where Marketing wanted all the colors to match (on the screen, on paper, on plastic, on on fabric) and it was a mess.